# How to get a state of filtered array?

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a table which is filled with an array of objects filtered with a pipe. I want to get the actual state of filtered content without keeping it as variable in component. Is it possible?
 Let's say, I have a table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of objects | filter:inputVal">
    <td>{{obj.foo}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.bar}}</td>
</tr>
```

and I want to disable button by the following condition:

```
<button type="button" (ng-disabled)="(objects | filter:inputVal).length != 1">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `[disabled]`

Try like this:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="(objects | filter:inputVal).length != 1">Remove</button>
```